# How to correctly use an alarm with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So i tried several ways and followed multiple guides to try an update my SharedReferences but it simply doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea why.

I tried to register a Broadcast Receiver in code and at the moment im trying it inside the Manifest.xml.

The OnCreate() is brought down to the ( I think) relevant parts.

MainActivity.java

```
public static final String alarm = "com.example.aufgaben_planer.alarm";
public static final String sharedPrefs = "com.example.aufgaben_planer.MONTH";
SharedPreferences prefs;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        prefs = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        timingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        timingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17); // At the hour you want to fire the alarm
        timingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55); // alarm minute
        timingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // and alarm second
        long intendedTime = timingCal.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MonthManager.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction(alarm);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.temp_tasks);
        tv.setText(prefs.getString("REC","NOT CALLED"));

    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aufgaben_planer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity android:name=".Add_job" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MonthManager" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.aufgaben_planer.alarm"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

MonthManager.java

```
public class MonthManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("BISASAM","triggered");
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.sharedPrefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = preferences.edit();
        editPrefs.putString("REC","Receiver called");
        editPrefs.commit();
        for(int i=1;i<Jobs.month_length;i++){
            editPrefs.putString(Integer.toString((i-1)),preferences.getString(Integer.toString(i),"#"));
            Log.d("BISASAM",i+" to "+(i-1));
        }
        editPrefs.putString(Integer.toString(30),"");
        editPrefs.commit();
    }
}
```

As added in the Code, I was expecting to see a "Receiver called" in the TextView, which is in the MainActivity, but I just get the "NOT CALLED".
It seems as if the alarm is set correctly, because on the adb shell dumpsys alarm it is listed.

Edit: For whatever reason it works now in the emulator, but it is always waiting for the debugger to attach.

Edit: As a last question: How can I make sure, the OnReceive() is finished when I reopen the application. Because now I can open it, then have to close it and after I reopen it everythings fine.

Comment: Is the alarm Receiver running? Are you seeing the log prints there? Are you sure the designated time is as you're expecting? With a 24hr clock value, you should be setting `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, instead of `HOUR`. Are you using the same `SharedPreferences` in `MainActivity` as in the Receiver? You don't show how you're getting `prefs` there. Are you aware that the `TextView` won't automatically change its value if the alarm fires while `MainActivity` is open? You'd have to restart the `Activity`. Are you somehow checking if any of those other values are being set?

Comment: Sorry for missing the prefs. 1. Im not sure how to check if the alarm receiver is running. 2 . No I don't see any Log 3. Yes they both refer to the same string. 4. Yes I am because the alarm should be run in the background so after it was fired and I restart the app it still should work. 5. Which other values are u referring to? I can't add the prefs atm but they are loaded the same as in MonthManager OnReceive

Comment: 1.) The logs would be a good indicator. 2.) Make sure you don't have any filters set that might be excluding those. You could also do something more noticeable from the Receiver, like a `Notification`, or even a `Toast`. 4.) If that's how you're checking, make sure that `MainActivity` actually finishes before checking again; e.g., back press out of it, swipe it from Recents, etc. 5.) I meant all those other values you're putting in the Receiver, in the loop, and after.

Comment: Oh, and remove that `process` attribute on the `<receiver>` element. That's possibly the main issue. Any reason why you're trying to run that in a separate process?

Comment: removing the process attribute didnt change anything. It was added there, because i saw in another post, that you should be able to debug it that way, but the process never showed up.

Comment: I tried adding a breakpoint in the OnReceive(), but when debugging it seems like the function is not even called. Neither a toast is opened nor a Log found in the Debug-Output

Comment: UPDATE: When the app is openend the Breakpoint gets hit. But I need the Receiver also the get "alarmed", when the app is closed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. Alarms, in general, do not depend on the current state of your app. If your alarm is not firing while your app is not running, and the device is awake, then that's some specific manufacturer restriction. On newer Android versions, however, certain alarms will not fire while the device is in doze mode. All of the repeating alarms are like that. If that's what you mean is happening, then you'll want to use an "allow while idle" alarm. You can find more information in [the `AlarmManager` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).

Comment: Well the alarm is working now, but with a slight problem. The OnReceive() is called, but the execution of the function only works when the app is open. So my background changing doesnt work, which means I have to start the app, then close it and restart it to finally get the "Receiver called" listed.

Comment: As I mentioned above, if your Receiver is not running specifically while your app is not running, then that is a manufacturer restriction. I've heard of several that do prevent apps from doing anything in the background. You might be able find some switch in the device Settings, or in some separate security-related app, that controls that restriction.

Comment: Is there any way to find out if the Receiver is running?

Comment: Logs, breakpoints, side effects like modified preferences or other files, `Notification`s, etc. I don't really understand what you're asking, now.

Comment: Do you know something about the prevention related to Samsung devices ?